# Hiding many divs with one onclick function

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am looking for a Javascript solution for this problem. I have the following HTML:

```
<div id = "container">
  <div id = "data">
    <div>
      <h3> Address</h3>
      <b>Expand...</b>
      <div id="content">ul. Pomorska</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3> Telefon </h3> <b>Expand...</b>
      <div id="content">26565352</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Email</h3>
      <b>Expand...</b>
      <div id="content">asdasdag@aga.com</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to hide the content div when an onclick Expand is made. So far I have made a function which hides the content divs and tries to assign an event handler to the  node.

```
function hideinfo() {
  var node = document.getElementById("data");
  var contactdata = node.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for(var i=0; i<contactdata.length;i++) {
    if(contactdata[i].id == "content") {
      alert(contactdata[i].previousSibling.innerHTML);
      contactdata[i].previousSibling.addEventListener('click',ShowHide,false);
      contactdata[i].style.display="none";
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the alert displays undefined. Why can't it see the  node? Is there a better way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: is jquery as an option ?

Comment: no, this is a thing for uni, we are to see how js is handled by different browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `previousSibling` is most likely the text node before the `div` element. You probably want to use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.previousElementSibling) instead :)

In most browser today, [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which lets you use CSS selectors for finding elements, is also a good alternative (IE8+)

Comment: The MDN doc pages I linked have a compatibility table.

Answer (score 1):

> The previousSibling property returns the previous sibling node (the previous node in the same tree level) of the selected element

which returns in your case the TEXT node.

As you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu383/

```
alert(contactdata[i].previousSibling.nodeName);
```

You are better of using the querySelectorAll.

Also you can't have multiple divs with the SAME id, use class instead.